# Wordpress dequeing/deregistering style not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Enfold theme and using `functions.php`, I want to dequeue unneeded styles.

From their source code, I can see that for example 'contact.css' is enqueued like this:

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'avia-module-contact', AviaBuilder::$path['pluginUrlRoot'] . 'avia-shortcodes/contact/contact.css', array( 'avia-layout' ), false );
```

So to my `functions.php`, I added this:

```php
function remove() {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'avia-module-contact' ); // this works, no more contact.js
        wp_dequeue_style( 'avia-module-contact' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'avia-module-contact' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove', 100 );
```

This is not working, I still see `contact.css` being loaded in the header. However the `contact.js` is gone, that seems to work.
How can I properly dequeue it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong hook, for js it is `wp_print_scripts`, for styles it's `wp_print_styles`.